# Ring of integers is integrally closed

Tags: number-theory

In Chapter 12 of Rosen and Ireland's *A Classical Introduction To Modern Number Theory*, they ask to prove that every ring of integers $D$ of some field $F\supseteq \mathbb{Q}$ is integrally closed. That is, if $\alpha\in F$ is a root of some monic polynomial with coefficients in $D$, then $\alpha\in D$. In order to prove this, the following fact must be used: that for a $\mathbb{Z}$-module $V$, if $\alpha\beta\in V$ for every $\beta\in V$, then $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer.

I don't have many ideas about how to prove this. Suppose $\alpha^n+\cdots +a_1\alpha+a_0=0$ for some $a_i\in D$. One might use the fact that the linear combinations of the coefficients $a_i$ form a $\mathbb{Z}$-module but I don't know how to use this.

**EDIT:**

To be clear, a $\mathbb{Z}$-module is defined in this book as follows:

*A subset $V \subset \mathbb{C}$ is called a $\mathbb{Z}$ module if
(a) $\beta_1,\beta_2\in V$ implies that $\beta_1\pm\beta_2\in V$ and
(b) there exist elements $\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_l\in V$ such that every $\beta\in V$ is of the form $\sum_{i=1}^l b_i\beta_i$ with $b_i\in \mathbb{Z}$.*

Comment: The hint given can be used to show that the set of algebraic integers is closed under multiplication.

Comment: Are you trying to show that the integral closure is integrally closed (exercise 27 of chapter 12 in the second edition)?  I won't post an answer but if you want to look up a proof, this is in every algebra book, e.g. the first few pages of Atiyah and MacDonald, chapter 5.

Comment: @yoyo, my question is on page 122: "The ring $D$ is also integrally closed. This means that if $\alpha\in F$ satisfies a monic polynomial with coefficients in $D$ then $\alpha\in D$. This is not too hard to
establish using Proposition 6.1.4.". And proposition 6.1.4. says exactly: "Let $W$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$ module and suppose that $\omega\in \mathbb{C}$ is such that
$\omega\gamma\in W$ for all $\gamma\in W$. Then $W$ is an algebraic integer".

Comment: Use the equivalence $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer $\iff \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}-$module.

Comment: The ring of integers of a field of numbers is much more than integrally closed.It is a ring of Dedekind, i. e. it is noetherian, integrally closed and all (non-zero) prime ideal is maximal.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways.

First, you can consider $\alpha$ as a matrix $M$ applied to $D$ with basis $\beta_i$. By Cayley Hamilton, the determinant of $xI-M$ is a monic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$ which is solved by $M$ and so has $\alpha$ as a root.

Second, $D$, being finitely generated over the integers, is a quotient module of $\mathbb Z^n$ which is Noetherian, so it’s Noetherian.

Let $b$ be any nonzero element of $D$. Then, let $I_k$ be the submodule generated by $b,\alpha b,\dots, \alpha^k b$.  We have that $I_k$ is an ascending chain of submodules, so it eventually stops increasing because it’s Noetherian. That is, there is some positive $N$ such that $I_N=I_{N-1}$, so $\alpha^N b\in I_{N-1}$, so $\alpha^Nb$ is a sum of integer multiples of $\alpha^kb$ for $k<N$.  Dividing by $b$ gives the desired monic polynomial.

Comment: Presumably $V=D$ here?

Comment: Yes, fixed that.

Answer (score -1):

One way to try.

Consider the set V as defined in the question, which is a Z-module.

Let α be an element of F such that αβ∈V for every β∈V.

You want to show that α is an algebraic integer, meaning it is a root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients.

Consider a polynomial equation with coefficients in D: α^n + a_1α^(n-1) + ... + a_n = 0, where a_i∈D. This equation expresses α as a root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in D.

Express the equation as α^n = -a_1α^(n-1) - ... - a_n.

Since α^n and all terms on the right-hand side are elements of V (as αβ∈V for every β∈V and V is a Z-module), their linear combinations (including ∑ biα^i) are also elements of V.

Now, for each term biα^i in the linear combination, consider the equation α^i = (-1/b_i) * (a_1α^(i-1) + ... + a_i). Since α^i∈V and V is a Z-module, the right-hand side of the equation is also an element of V.

This implies that biα^i is an algebraic integer, as it's a linear combination of elements in V.

The sum of algebraic integers is also an algebraic integer. Therefore, the linear combination ∑ biα^i is an algebraic integer.

This concludes that α^n + a_1α^(n-1) + ... + a_n = 0 is an algebraic integer.

Thus, α is an algebraic integer, as it's a root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients.

By utilizing the properties of Z-modules and algebraic integers, you can show that if αβ∈V for every β∈V, then α is an algebraic integer. This result aligns with the fact that every ring of integers D of some field F⊇Q is integrally closed, as desired.

Comment: Unfortunately, this try flops. The sentence "Thus, α is an algebraic integer..." is a non-sequitur. You claim it holds because $\alpha$ is "a root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients" [presumably in $D$], but you already knew that before doing any of this work. Therefore the proof can be shortened to just the last paragraph, which merely declares the result true.

Comment: Thanks your absolutely right my mistake thank you pointing it out.